# Objective-C - Check FileVault status in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, filevault

I am working on a Cocoa application (Objective-C) where it needs to determine if the `FileVault` is turned on. I tried searching the `.plist` for `FileVault` but no success.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance :) cheers

Comment: This is not an API but at least there is [fdesetup tool](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fdesetup.8.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple via `NSTask`:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/fdesetup"];
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"status", nil]];

    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [task launch];

    NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog (@"%@", string); // FileVault is Off/On.
}
```

There's likely a way to check via `SecKeychain`, although for a quick check that might be overkill.

Comment: Thank you so much @l'L'l it was a great help :D